# Returning a struct in a void func()

Tags: c, gcc

I'm trying to compile my code from the old MS-DOS days and this doesn't seem to work with GCC:

```c
    typedef struct { int x,y,z; } vector;

    inline void vect_add(vector& c,vector a, vector b)
    {
        c.x=a.x+b.x;
        c.y=a.y+b.y;
        c.z=a.z+b.z;
    }
```

Basically I'm trying to return a struct which is later used as vector.x etc instead of rewriting it as a pointer to struct and rewriting all as vector->x etc

see **(vector& c,**

Comment: C does not have the C++ style reference syntax which you are trying to use.

Comment: C doesn't have references. You need to *emulate* it using pointers.

Comment: As mentioned by @EugeneSh. the syntax you try to use is C++. Are you sure that the project you're trying to build is not a C++ project?

Comment: I assume this _used_ to work? So you might need to make sure GCC correctly runs in C++ mode, not in C mode.

Comment: What's the name of the source code file? Are you using `g++` or `gcc`?

Comment: watcom c/c++ allowed it to compile as .c as far as i can remember it seems to be a silimar feature to c+= or c++ :)

Comment: @mareque Certainly you want `int x,y,z;`, not `int c,y,z;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is possibly valid C++, but it's not valid C.

In C, you need to use a pointer, a global var, or actually return a struct.

```c
typedef struct { int x, y, z; } vector;

inline void vect_add(vector* c, vector a, vector b)
{
    c->x = a.x + b.x;
    c->y = a.y + b.y;
    c->z = a.z + b.z;
}

vect_add(&c, a, b);
```